# utilizar o sim não no access e c# usando checkbox no c# marcação verdairo ou false

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Estou a criar um quiz e as perguntas estão a se repetir. Pretendo usar o  checkbox quando verificar se a pergunta já foi usada ou não o mesmo checkbox.

Estou usar o seguinte código:

```cs
            int[] num = new int[13];
            System.Random aleat = new System.Random();
            int valomaximo = 12;
            int valorminimo = 1;
            int varial = aleat.Next(valorminimo, valomaximo);
            varial = aleat.Next(valorminimo, valomaximo) + 1;

            OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand consuta = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataReader Leitor;
            conexao.ConnectionString = Angola.BUscar_Caminho();
            conexao.Open();
            consuta.CommandText = "SELECT *FROM Perguntas  where NumeroDeOrdem = " + varial + " AND Nivel = " + textoNivelFinal.Text + " ";
            consuta.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            consuta.Connection = conexao;
            Leitor = consuta.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable tepergunta = new DataTable();
            tepergunta.Load(Leitor);

            foreach (DataRow data in tepergunta.Rows)
            {
                string Pergunta = data["Perguntas"].ToString();
                // btperguta.Text = (Leitor["Perguntas"].ToString());
                string A = data["A"].ToString();
                string B = data["B"].ToString();
                string C = data["C"].ToString();
                string D = data["D"].ToString();
                string RC = data["Respostascertas"].ToString();
                bool estado = Convert.ToBoolean(data["Fechada"]);
                btperguta.Text = Pergunta;
                btrespa.Text = A;
                btrespb.Text = B;
                btrespc.Text = C;
                btrespd.Text = D;
                label1.Text = RC;
                checkBox1.Checked= estado;
                checkBox1.Text = varial.ToString();
                checkBox1.Checked = true;

                data["Fechada"] = checkBox1.Checked;
                checkBox1.Checked = true;
                
                estado = checkBox1.Checked;

                if (checkBox1.Checked==true)
                {
                    estado = true;
                    data["Fechada"] = checkBox1.Checked;
                    checkBox1.Checked = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    estado = false;
                }
```

Comment: e qual é a sua dúvida? não ficou claro

Comment: Como pegar o valor do checkbook para o access

Comment: `data["nome-do-campo"]` agora como converter depende de tipo de dados que está na tabela. Normalmente converte para bool se o campo for to tipo sim/não

Comment: é como esta   bool estado = Convert.ToBoolean(data["Fechada"]);

Comment: então não entendi o pq faz `estado = checkBox1.Checked;`, isso vai sobrescrever o valor do banco, e tbm o if a seguir não faz sentido, não bastaria por o valor do banco no checkbox? algo assim `checkBox1.Checked = estado`?

Comment: Ok ideia  se estivar marcada no bd  a pergunta não vou tará aperecer durante o jogo por usei o if

Comment: ok, acho que é então se inverter o `estado = checkBox1.Checked;` para `checkBox1.Checked= estado` :)

Comment: ok   vou tentar fazer desta forma

Comment: Não deu certo  desta maneiracheckBox1.Checked= estado